# how to pass a bitfield in by reference

Tags: c++, bit-fields

Note a question with nearly the exact same title already exists, but is asking a very different question.

Say I want a method that takes a bitfield reference or pointer as an argument.  This isn't legal, but perhaps an example would clarify:

```
class Foo {

  unsigned a:2, b:2, c:2;

  bool Bar( unsigned* px:2 ) { *px = a; return true; };
}

Foo foo;
if ( foo.Bar( &foo.b ) )
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
```

I could write Bar as a macro:

```
#define BAR( pfoo, field ) ( ( (pfoo)->field = (pfoo)->a ), true )

Foo foo;
if ( BAR( &foo, b ) )
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
```

Many place where you'd write some such macro in C you can now handle with function templates.  Is there a template solution to writing the above Bar() method legally in C++11 or later?

Comment: The hypothetical example with `unsigned* px: 2` would not have solved the problem as it only contains size information, but you'd also need the position information in the word, which sort of shows why this would not be useful feature.

Comment: Alternative would be to simply pass in `foo.a` to your method as `unsigned` parameter and assign it to `b`. But maybe your example is too simplified for that to work in your real use-case. Either way, not possible to take the address of or make a reference to a bit field.

Comment: @super your suggested change changes the question too much.  It would require Bar to know what the destination of the assignment is.  The key thing in this problem is that we **don't know**, and that's why we need to pass something by reference.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: *The hypothetical example with unsigned* px: 2 would not have solved the problem as it only contains size information*... Well, if C++ supported this, it *wouldn't* only contain size information, clearly!  That offset could for instance be an invisible parameter following px called `_bitfield_offset_px`, and any reference to `px` is automatically converted with `<<` or `>>` operations as needed.  I think it'd be easy to do, if they felt like doing it.

Comment: This reminds me to the specialization [std::vector<bool>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) which is commonly considered as unlucky or broken somehow. Condensing the individual `bool` elements as bits makes them in-addressable by a plain pointer or reference. The [std::vector<bool>::reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) has to be used instead. The `std::vector<>::data()` is even not provided. TL;DR: I believe the usage of bit-fields has to be done with care - it breaks the usual applications which may be done for other types.

Comment: @SwissFrank That's not really clear from your question alone. The example method knows **what** to assign to `px` but needs `px` by pointer/reference. My suggestion would be the opposite, doesn't know what to assign, but knows where to put the value. But as I said, that's highly dependent on your use case.

Comment: @super, in my program I don't KNOW where to put the value, which is why I want to pass in the bitfield by reference!  I can't simply decree that I DO know where to put the result, on the grounds that would easier to program!  I thank you for your interest and very helpful attitude though; sorry the description isn't quite clear.

Comment: @SwissFrank I think you are missing the point. I made a comment with an alternative solution, since the question doesn't clearly state the things you are saying in your comments. It's about making the question better. Hint: You can edit your question.

Comment: many thanks @super but I feel the title itself sums up the question succinctly, as does the second line of the question body, and your responses don't answer the question.  This is my last comment on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to cobble up something that acts as a bitfield reference in a rather inefficient and roundabout way.

```
template<typename underlying>
struct bitfield_ref
{
    virtual underlying get() { return getter(); }
    virtual void set(underlying val) { setter(val); }
    bitfield_ref(std::function<underlying()> getter, std::function<void(underlying)> setter) :
      getter(getter), setter(setter) {}
    std::function<underlying()> getter;
    std::function<void(underlying)> setter;
};

#define BITFIELD_REF(s,m) bitfield_ref<decltype(s.m)>( \
      [&s]() { return s.m; }, \
      [&s](decltype(s.m) v) { s.m = v; })
```

It can be used this way

```
  struct moo
  {
      unsigned int a : 2;
      unsigned int b : 3;
  };

  unsigned int test(bitfield_ref<unsigned int> x)
  {
      x.set(3);
      return x.get() + 1;
  }

  int main()
  {
      moo m;
      std::cout << test(BITFIELD_REF(m, a)) << "\n";
  }
```

It is further possible to get rid of `get` and `set` by defining a conversion operator and an assignment operator (and all of the compound assignments to go with it), this is omitted for brevity.